# Somehow, edit/delete has been changed to node->title/edit or node->title/delete for one of my project. Can anyone have idea what could be a reason?

Tags: nodes

Somehow, edit/delete has been changed to node->title/edit or node->title/delete for one of my project. Can anyone have idea what could be a reason?

Any lead towards the debugging would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On one of my projects, for this kind of functionality I have used [Sub-path URL Alises](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpath_alias) module. Maybe it's enabled on your project ?